# How to use Skip() and Take() with IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that contains a repeater and it's datasouce is set using an IEnumerable object that contains data returned from query in code. The repeater has paging functionality and displays a custom number of records for each page.

I don't want to load all the data each time the user clicks the next button to see the next page of records in the repeater. How can I make it IQueryable and use Skip() and Take() to display only the records needed for that page?

I have the following code:

```
//Code that assigns query to repeater data source
DataSet = QueryGoesHere.ToArray(); // returns IEnumerable
repeater.DataSource = DataSet;
repeater.DataBind();

//Code that creates PagedDataSource - how can I update this to make it display only the records that are needed for the currently displayed page?

            objPds = new PagedDataSource();
            objPds.DataSource = DataSource
            objPds.AllowPaging = true;
            objPds.PageSize = 5;
            objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
            lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + objPds.PageCount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I get you right you want to use your own implementation istead of loading all data and then using the PagedDataSource right?

If so you have to make sure that `QueryGoesHere` is a Queryable supporting this (Linq2Sql or EF). Then you have to get the count of your date like this

```
var count = QueryGoesHere.Count();
```

and get the portion of data you want to display:

```
var skip = (curPageNumber - 1)*itemsPerPage;
var display = Math.Min(count - skip, itemsPerPage);
```

and just use

```
var displayedItems = QueryGoesHere.Skip(skip).Take(display).ToArray();
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The PagedList and the related extensions will be helpful to you. Please refer to: http://wekeroad.com/2007/12/10/aspnet-mvc-pagedlistt

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> SampleDataList(int startIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var sampleTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var page = TemporaryData().Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize);
        var query = from p in page
                    select new
                    {
                        FirstColumn = p.Key,
                        SecondColumn = p.Value
                    };

        foreach (var row in query)
            sampleTable.Add(row.FirstColumn, row.SecondColumn);

        return sampleTable;
    }
```

following link will help you to understand how to use pagination with repeater

http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-use-custom-pagination.html

Comment: `skip` should come before `take`, no?